# Extract pdf´s text with itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

im trying to extract the text from a pdf, but i cant make it, i use itext´s library but the method return null, here the code..

```
public String pdfLoad(File archivoPDF) {
    String texto="";
    try {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(archivoPDF.getPath());
        System.out.println(reader.getNumberOfPages());
        for(int i=0 ; i<reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            texto= texto+ PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i);
        }
        reader.close();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Excepcion cargando pdf" +e.getStackTrace());
    }
    return texto;
```

and the method return null. i also tryed with pdfBox but doesnt worked.

Comment: Perhaps the text is actually an image

Comment: Doesn't page numbering here start with 1 instead of 0?

Comment: If the text is actually an image, then use the iText add-on pdfOCR.

Comment: Open the PDF in Acrobat and try to extract text from there. Do you get anything?

Comment: yes, the problem was in the for, just had to do i<=reader.getNumberPages()